# I want to reuse socket after shutdown(java)

Tags: java, sockets

Declared variables

```
protected Socket fileSocket;
protected OutputStream os;
fileSocket = new Socket(host, port + 1);
os = fileSocket.getOutputStream();
```

and uses in next code

```
File file;
FileInputStream fis;            
int readBytes;
try
{
    if(fileSocket.isOutputShutdown())
    {
        fileSocket.setKeepAlive(true);//this line
    }
    sendToServer(message);              
    bufFileName = message.toCharArray();
    fileName = new String(bufFileName, 6, bufFileName.length - 6);              
    file = new File(fileName);
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    while ((readBytes = fis.read()) != -1)
    {
        os.write(readBytes);
        os.flush();
    }
    fileSocket.shutdownOutput();
    fis.close();
    clientUI.display("Trans complete");
```

I send a file and shutdown fileSocket.
And I want to reuse filesocket, but can't find Appropriate method.
What method or operation should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Just instantiate a new socket. You can't use a socket you've already closed. That would like trying to do file operations on a file stream you've already closed.

Answer (score 0):

setKeepAlive() doesn't do what you think. Once you've shutdown the output on a socket, you can't do any more output on the socket. Once you've closed it you can't reuse it at all.